# How to collect sets as values from a map in java stream?

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have such structure:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> structureIdWithUserIds
```

And I need to process all values(Sets) and concatinate them in one `Set` of Integers. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: You can use `structureIdWithUserIds.values()` to get a collection of `Set<Integer>` and follow the answer in the linked post on how to merge.

Comment: @Thiyagu yeah I tried Set<Integer> 
ids = Stream.of(structureIdWithUserIds.values()).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet()) but intelij underscores (Set::stream) so it does not work

Comment: `structureIdWithUserIds.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());`